# IIS 6.1 - redirect - but getting 500 error

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-7, http-redirect

1. I created a new IIS site and pointing to a directory and the directory has no files
2. Made sure the bindings are good meaning old url is here inside.company.com
3. Clicked on the "http redirect" and put in my new url inside.newcompany.com

when i type inside.newcompany.com is resolves thru browser so i made sure that url resolves and good to go. however, the old inside.company.com should redirect if i did it correct (step 1 thru 3). instead I am getting 500 error.

could you please help me on where next i should look.

Sorry: It's IIS 6.1 (build 7601: sp1)

Comment: Looks like app pool account need access to the file share folder.

Comment: Gave "Everyone" read access to the folder and no more 500. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Grant "Everyone" account read access to the web folder and 500 went away.